# Swift return values of different types in function based on conditions

Tags: swift, function, if-statement, return-type

I am new in Swift and have a small question.

I want to build a function which can return values of different types based on the conditions. What return type should I use?? Below is the function. I use "??" as the placeholder. Can anybody help to change the "??" with correct return type?? Thanks!!

```
fun Req_amt() -> ?? {
    if let input_amt = readLine() {
        if let amount = Float(input_amt) {
            return amount
        } else {
            return "Bad number."
        }
    } else {
        return "Bad input."
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general programming principle, about "crossing streams" between your happy (result-yielding) and failure (error-yielding) code paths. Otherwise, you might end up in a situation where you forget to check for an error value, and you treat the error as a result. For example, suppose this function was to return a `String` in the happy case. The result would always be `String`, with no indication that you should check it for "special values" which indicate error. This is the founding idea behind `Optional<T>`, `Result<T>` and thrown errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a `Float?` with `nil` to signify an error in general, or you could return a Float but with `throws` and throw an Error to give further specific info such as “Bad number” or “Bad input”. It sounds like the latter is what you want here.